# +(void) initialize in objective-c class static variables constructor

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, interface, constructor

I found some sample code from [here](http://blog.devedup.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/DecimalPointNumberPadOS4-v3.zip).

```
static UIImage *backgroundImageDepressed;

/**
 *
 */
@implementation DecimalPointButton

+ (void) initialize {
    backgroundImageDepressed = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"decimalKeyDownBackground.png"] retain];
}
```

Is it something like this - `+(void) initialize` method initialize static variables of a class ( interface ) in Objective C? I have never seen this before.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This `+initialize` method is described in [*The Objective-C Programming Language*](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/articles/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-TPXREF119).

> The runtime system sends an `initialize` message to every class object **before the class receives any other messages** and after its superclass has received the `initialize`  message. This gives the class a chance to set up its runtime environment before it’s used. If no initialization is required, you don’t need to write an `initialize` method to respond to the message.

For example, when `[DecimalPointButton alloc]` is called, the runtime will check if `[DecimalPointButton initialize]` has been called. If not, it will `+initialize` the class. This ensure the `backgroundImageDepressed` image is ready *before* any instances of DecimalPointButton are constructed.